Extract by mask jagged edges
I have a raster with cell size (12.5), I tried both extracted by mask and clip tools to extract the raster to the plots of the study area (Shapefile), but it resulted with jagged edges.
I tried reduced the cell size to (0.6) in the environment of the extraction tool, the edges almost worked well, but the inside map pixelated.
Any suggestion to fix this?



There are no pixels which have curved edges, they are all rectangles. Only horizontal and vertical selections can have straight lines, otherwise the result is jagged. WIth smaller pixel size that is not as visible. Your first image is suspicious, maybe the rendering software has rendered polygons with a better resolution on top of the pixels. The second image is what I suppose to see with reduced pixel size.

The smooth pixels in the first image are because of the display theme (Cubic). In the second image when I use this theme (Cubic), it does not work. Additionally, when I reduced the cell size in the second image, the pixels extended beyond the plot's limits @user30184

What software do you use?

ArcMap 10.8.2 @user30184
